# What is use of HDWalletProvider in Truffle config?

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-deployment

The sample code here for deploying to **Ropsten** used `HDWalletProvider` and a `mnemonic` in the configuration, but I am not sure I understand its purpose.

> Is this just telling it the account that will become the contract owner when you deploy?

```js
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");

// 12-word mnemonic
var mnemonic = process.env.NMEMONIC;

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },
    ropsten: {
      provider: new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://ropsten.infura.io/"),
      network_id: 3 // official id of the ropsten network
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Truffle HDWallet provider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider) is a convenient and easy to configure network connection to ethereum through infura.io (or any other compatible provider).

For example the HDWallet provider add some features required by Truffle that are not available with infura like event filtering and transaction signing.

Comment: Is HDWalletProvider secure for production use? Or only testing?

Comment: @MH I didn't have any problem when I used it, but I can't vouch for it to be error free. In my experience Truffle developers were fast to respond when I reported other issues with ganache/truffle.

Comment: I was more asking about the security. Can I use HDWalletProvider with a wallet and be sure someone isn't viewing my mnemonic? I understand if you dont know. I wanted to hear from everyone.

Comment: @MH A better place to ask about that should be reddit.com/r/ethdev or reddit.com/r/ethereum

Answer (score 4):

When deploying a contract you eventually need to sign a transaction with an account (with a private key).

This account management process is handled by the provider, in this case, the [@truffle/hdwallet-provider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/develop/packages/hdwallet-provider) (Note that [truffle-hdwallet-provider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider) is deprecated). This could be another provider like Metamask or a local Web3 provider.

Answer (score 0):

HDWallet provider is used by truffle when we deploy the contract however metamask providers are used when we want to interact with the contract in the browser.